# How would I use each_with_index for a 2d array in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 2d array of objects and integers @user_double_array. It looks like this.

```
[[#<User object>, integer], [#<User object>, integer]]
```

I'm calling this in my view

```
<% @user_double_array.each do |user, percentage| %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to have the number of each iteration so I tried this

```
<% @user_double_array.each_with_index do |user, percentage, index| %>
<% end %>
```

But I recieve an error when using user such as

```
 "undefined method "email" for #<Array:0x007ff793c42240>"
```

How can I keep track of each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an array of arrays, when you iterate, each time the block variable gives one array, again on which you can call `.first` and `.last` to make things work. So,

```
@user_double_array = [[#<User object>, integer], [#<User object>, integer]]
```

You can iterate like this

```
<% @user_double_array.each_with_index do |user_array, index| %>
  <%= index %>
  <%= user_array.first.email %> // user_array.first holds #<User object>
  <%= user_array.last %> //gives integer
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did the job. Thank you very much, Anees. I would not have been able to figure this out myself.

Comment: @Goeken Glad that I could help!